# What does the property 'isExclusiveMode' do in microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.acceptmessagesessionasync

Tags: azureservicebus

In the MSDN documentation for microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.acceptmessagesessionasync

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.acceptmessagesessionasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_AcceptMessageSessionAsync_System_String_System_Boolean_

The is a property to use isExclusiveMode for a accepting a service bus session, but it is unclear what it does to me. Something with locking?

Answer (score 0):

In short, an exclusive mode ensures that there's only one consumer at a time for a given message in the queue. Here's a bit of an excerpt from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#settling-receive-operations):

*"The Peek-Lock mode tells the broker that the receiving client wants to settle received messages explicitly. The message is made available for the receiver to process, while held under an exclusive lock in the service so that other, competing receivers cannot see it. The duration of the lock is initially defined at the queue or subscription level and can be extended by the client owning the lock, via the RenewLock operation."*

Hope this helps!